# header appears different on pages - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, indexing

I am having an issue where my header information appears differently on pages but fine on the homepage (index.php of course). I've checked the other files I use on the site and they are calling the same header.php file so I can't figure out where this issue lies.

Here is a link to the dev site: http://ultrasportslive.tv/blog

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I compared the header in the two pages and I can see there's a difference between h1 and h2. In the H2 css there's the code below code that is affecting the second page. Check on firebug.

```
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://www.ultrasportslive.tv/blog/

```
<div id="header">
<div id="inside-header">
<div class="logo-wrap">
<h1 id="logo" class="image-logo">
<div class="social-media-icon">
</div>
<div class="secondary-navigation">
</div>
</div>
```

http://www.ultrasportslive.tv/blog/race-results/

```
<div id="header">
<div id="inside-header">
<div class="logo-wrap">
<h2 id="logo" class="image-logo">
<div class="social-media-icon">
</div>
<div class="secondary-navigation">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been checking with an inspector and did notice that but now I've noticed that there is an else statement for the h2 version in the header.php file - without your help I may never have noticed that. Thank you!